# Many to Many DB relationship feathersjs version 5

Tags: feathersjs

I created 2 services with feathersjs v5, service team and service player with feathersjs cli.
The schema of each contains id and name attributes. I use knex to connect to sqlite DB

I tried to implement many to many DB relationship between team and player services using resolvers and adpaters but I was not able to